# Calculating sum(column) based on other column values in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table

```
Id   quantity    level_1     group_1
1    13          1           1
2    10          1           1
3    10          0           1
4    10          0           1
5    20          1           0
```

I want to neglect **level_1='0'** from the above table.

I want to calculate the sum(quantity) of **group_1='1'** and **group_1='0'** separately satisfying the first condition above.

**Expected result:**

```
sum_quantity   sum_quantity_2_Not_Valid
23             20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below

**Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE #TAB (Id INT, quantity INT, level_1 INT, group_1 INT)
INSERT INTO #TAB

SELECT 1, 13, 1, 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 10, 1, 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 10, 0, 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 10, 0, 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 20, 1, 0
```

Use `SUM` with `CASE`

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE level_1 WHEN 1 THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS sum_quantity
, SUM(CASE level_1 WHEN 0 THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS sum_quantity_2_Not_Valid 
FROM #TAB
WHERE group_1 =1
```

And the Result will be

```
+--------------+--------------------------+
| sum_quantity | sum_quantity_2_Not_Valid |
+--------------+--------------------------+
|           23 |                       20 |
+--------------+--------------------------+
```

If your intention to get values by grouping `group_1`

```
SELECT [1] AS sum_quantity, [0] AS sum_quantity_2_Not_Valid  FROM (
SELECT group_1,
SUM(CASE level_1 WHEN 1 THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS sum_quantity
FROM #TAB
GROUP BY group_1
)AS A
PIVOT
(
    MAX( sum_quantity) FOR group_1 IN ([1],[0])
)PVT
```

Comment: Mirz,He don't need level 0 value.He want to neglect level_1='0'

Comment: @shakeer Miza From the question : " I want to neglect level_1='0' from the above table." Are you doing that?

Comment: You can find that in my second solution @VDK

Answer (score 1):

```
Use SUB query to get result :

CREATE TABLE #Table(Id INT,  quantity INT, level_1 INT, group_1 INT)
INSERT INTO #Table(Id ,  quantity , level_1 , group_1)
SELECT 1,13,1,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,10,1,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,10,0,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 4,10,0,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 5,20,1,0

SELECT SUM(A.quantity) sum_quantity,SUM(B.quantity) sum_quantity_2_Not_Valid 
FROM 
(
   SELECT SUM(quantity) quantity,group_1
   FROM #Table
   WHERE level_1 = 1 AND group_1 = 1
   GROUP BY group_1
 )A,
 (
   SELECT SUM(quantity) quantity,group_1
   FROM #Table
   WHERE level_1 = 1 AND group_1 = 0
   GROUP BY group_1
  )B
```

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Comment: Nice query mate, but if you use CASE statements, you can keep it all in one SELECT statement.

Answer (score 1):

This will be the answer, as he wants to exclude **level_1='0'** :

```
SELECT SUM(CASE group_1 WHEN 1 THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS sum_quantity
     , SUM(CASE group_1 WHEN 0 THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS sum_quantity_2_Not_Valid 
FROM table
WHERE level_1 <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this would do it :-

```
SELECT MAX(Valid_Sum) AS Final_Valid_Sum,
       MAX(Invalid_sum) AS Final_InValid_Sum
FROM
(
    SELECT SUM(quantity) Valid_Sum,
           0 AS Invalid_Sum
    FROM Table1
    WHERE level_1 <> 0
          AND group_1 = 1
    UNION
    SELECT 0,
           SUM(Quantity)
    FROM Table1
    WHERE level_1 <> 0
          AND group_1 = 0
);
```